# WatchKit : handleWatchKitExtensionRequest multiple instances

Tags: ios, watchkit

So I have a parent app that logs in to a server, creates a user etc.  I then use handleWatchKitExtensionRequest from the WatchApp to access the parent app but everything is null.

My question is, does handleWatchKitExtensionRequest get run in a different instance to the parent app?  I read somewhere it does but I just need this confirmed.

Thanks

Comment: What are you putting in the dictionary? If the data isn't serializable it will not work. You cannot, for example send a UIImage (it will be nil) but you can send a sting of NSData to represent it. It would be helpful to see the code and the data types you are trying to send.

Comment: An error probably occurred when running the code to handle your watch request. Double check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` returns nothing it means that the passed `reply` is never called. This is most probably due to `application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` runs into an error when the app is launched in background mode.

I had a similar issue with my app where I did some initializations on the app's  navigationController. It turned out that the navigationController is not accessible when the app is launched in background mode.

I would suggest to completely comment out the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and see if `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` calls its `reply`. If so, uncomment the code in `didFinishWithLaunchingWithOptions` step by step to detect the faulty code.

This may be really hard to track down because one cannot attach the debugger to the iPhone app at this time of launching.

Another pitfall:
The function signature of `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` has changed in Swift 1.2 without giving any compiler errors. It took me hours to figure that out.

Comment: You can fire the debugger up waiting for your process to run and it will attach immediately. Just go Debug->Attach to Process and put the Bundle name from your Info.plist (just watch out for spaces in the name). Works both on the device and simulator!